# Android studio flutter hot reload don't work after update

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

Recently I have updated my mac to Sonoma, also I have updated xcode and android studio. After that hot reload after save stopped work.

Checkbox "hot reload on save" checked.
Versions:
macbook: 14.1.1
android studio: 2023.2.1
flutter: 3.13.9
dart: 3.1.5

P.S. Already tried this checkbox[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYsRF.png)

I expecting hot reload will apply changes on the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like flutter plugin for Android Studio broken on the latest version, will wait for fix: [Jetbrain pugin review](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/reviews)

Answer (score 0):

If you updated your Flutter Intellij plugin, it's likely an issue with the last version, look here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/7040
Download an early version from here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions/stable (76.0.x worked for me) and manually downgrade, it should work.